# Partial integration paradox, from odd to even integrand

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I'm investigating the following integral:
$$
g(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x - i y} dx
$$
where I know that $f(-x) = - f(x)$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. (In practice I have data for $g(y)$, and am trying to find $f(x)$.) I can express this function as a Taylor series for y using the geometric series, which gives:
$$
g(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x - i y} dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (iy)^n \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x^{n+1}} dx
$$

Now comes the thing that's confusing me. Via partial integration, I find:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x^{n+1}} dx = \frac{f(x)}{x^{n+1}} \Bigg{\vert}_{-\infty}^{\infty} + (n + 1) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x^{n+2}} dx = (n+1) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x^{n+2}} dx
$$
where the first term was dropped because $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. But this means that if the integrand on the left hand side was even, on the right hand side I find one which is odd, i.e. zero. Hence, all coefficients in my Taylor expansion will be zero, and $g(y)$ will be zero, which I know it is not.

I feel stupid for having to ask this, but what am I doing wrong? Am I not allowed to do partial integration this way?

Comment: You should be careful about the infinite series. Under what condition does the geometric (uniformly) converge?

Comment: Some taylor expansion coefficients of some functions are always zero. E.g. $e^{\frac1{-x^2}}$

Comment: Your data $g$ is related to the Hilbert transform. You cannot just expand the integrand as geometric sum since the domain is whole of $\mathbb{R}$ and there is a convergence issue. You also cannot just use singular integral ($x^{-n}$ is the singular part) and apply integration by parts formula to it.

Comment: @Euduardo I know that, but I'm not sure that affects my problem with the partial integration, because even if I just started with the last equation, that problem would still persist. Furthermore, the taylor expansion of 1/(1-x) is always the geometric series, even if there is no convergence of the geometric series to 1/(1-x), right? And to push my luck even further, via analytic continuation we can still say this identification holds (https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/mark.coleman/MATH41022/Background/Background%20Analytic%20Continuation.pdf)

Comment: @Song Good point about the singular integral. So I would have to try contour integration instead, which is hard for an unknown function $f(x)$ which might itself have poles.

Comment: So you are investigating how to invert $g$ to get $f$. Then I recommend you to look for related topics such as Hilbert transform and Cauchy's transform. A holomorphic function $\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{f(x)}{x-z} dx$ defined on the upper half-plane $\Im{z}>0$ completely determines $f$, and given your data on the imaginary axis, there is at most one unique way to extend it to the whole plane. Its value on the real line $z= t\in\mathbb{R}$ is called the Hilbert transform $H$, and it admits an inversion formula (in fact, $H^{-1} = H$.)

Comment: @Song Thank you for the hint, I will look into that, we never studied Hilbert transforms. It is not exactly my situation since I know $g(y)$ on the real $y$ axis, but I might be able to do something similar nonetheless.